# How to change RESTful service synchronous to asynchronous using with jms queue and tomcat7

Tags: java, rest, jms, tomcat7, activemq-classic

I have created a Restful service using JAX-RS Jersey and deployed it on a tomcat 7 server. 
Now in client Browser  got  request and response  synchronously,its working fine.But now i will change asynchronously(Request and Response)
,It is possible ? if its  possible using with jms,Please suggest some way. and explain your answer with sample example.

Thanks and Regards,
Ramana.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible ?

yes it is, what you need to do is to have camel context defined and some routes defined for different events.

you can refer Using [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html) also other options like rabbitMQ etc available you can search and implement the solution based on your requirement.